# Why is it a disadvantage for Langevin dynamics to be non-reversible?

Tags: classical-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry, molecular-dynamics, stochastic-processes

In Molecular Dynamics, it is commun to use a Langevin thermostat to maintain a constant temperature. However, it is often written that the Langevin Thermostat not being time reversible is a disadvantage, why is that? What is wrong about not being time-reversible?

Comment: I think there is a generalized confusion. Langevin dynamics is reversible if the random force works backward. (Yes, there are reversible random number generators that can be used to implement Langevin dynamics). I think it is better to think that Langevin dynamics is non-deterministic (in the sense that the initial conditions --of the particles-- alone doesn't determine the outcome) rather than non-reversible. IMO a slightly better question would be "Why is it a disadvantage for Langevin dynamics to be non-deterministic?"